# Creating a huge 2D array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create a huge 2D array.

```
String[][] arr = new String[100000][100000];
```

But on execution, I get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

Other than increasing my heap space, how do I prevent getting this exception?

Comment: What is your data source? Do you really need all the data at the same time for processing? Otherwise you should consider writing data to a file, to free up space, adapt your processing algorithms to work on data batches, filter while writing, etc.

Comment: Do you actually have that much RAM? If yes, you can try to increase the heap size `-Xmx20g`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763079/what-are-the-xms-and-xmx-parameters-when-starting-jvms#14763095 But you should consider, that this won't be very fast. You should consider using a different algorithm or some kind of distributed cache / in memory DB.

Comment: @Mortiz Can you suggest an alternate algorithm for storing the huge data?

Answer (score 1):

Are you really going to use 100000 X 100000 positions,  If not and you are not sure about the max limit you can start with `List` of `List`s

declare like this `List<List<String>> arr = new ArrayList<List<String>>();`

When ever you want to call you need to do this `arr.get(0).get(1);` instead `arr[0][1]`

Comment: I am sure about the max limit. I can use a list, but while inserting, at some point, I would again end up out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that Oo It make 100000*100000 = 10.000.000.000 datas for your array !

You are out of your memory !!

Reduce the two number, i don't think that you need this much memory !

You can go on a :

```
String[][] arr = new String[14000][14000];
```

I tried and it works !